# Android tabs The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, tabs

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10985): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:The specified child already has a parent.You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

This is my XML `tabs_dettaglio.xml` I use for visual tabs:

Codice (XML): [Seleziona]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/relativeimg" 
    >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeimg1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeimg2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="220dip">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/relativeimg3" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <ImageView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="97dip">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**this is java code  :**

```
private void setTabs() {
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("1").setContent(new Intent(this,d.class)).setIndicator(addImg(1)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("2").setContent(new Intent(this,d.class)).setIndicator(addImg(2)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("3").setContent(new Intent(this,d.class)).setIndicator(addImg(3)));
}

private View addImg(int i) {
    int cc;
    int cc2;
    if(i==1) {
        cc = R.id.imageView3;
        cc2 = R.drawable.menu_oggi;
    } else if(i==2){
        cc = R.id.imageView2;
        cc2 = R.drawable.menu_ieri;
    } else {
        cc = R.id.imageView1;
        cc2 = R.drawable.menu_domani;
    }
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.tabs_dettaglio,null);                
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(cc);
    icon.setBackgroundResource(cc2);
    return icon;
}
```

Comment: Post your full error log, and tell us which line the exception occurs on (e.g. MyCode.java:34 is line 34 of MyCode.java)

Answer (score 5):

Should have following method. Note that the third argument of inflate is `false`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pane0, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a different class to each tab, not the same in the three tabs. You may want to create an xml file for each tab separately, not everything in one as you're doing right now.

Check the Tab layout tutorial ([here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)) to get an idea. Each `.setContent(intent);` refers to a different `intent` instance.

Comment: But also if I put a different intent and also I create three different xml files the error always present.... this is the log error

Comment: 05-15 02:32:53.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-15 02:32:53.681: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.android.infoconsumarori/it.android.infoconsumarori.dettaglio}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: You need to create three different **classes**, not three different **intents referring to the same class**.